# Datepicker not changing based on a button click?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, onchange

I have a two radio buttons like follows :-

```
<input type="radio" id="Users_gender_0" name="Users[gender]" value="1" onclick="getcaleder();" >Male
<input type="radio" id="Users_gender_1" name="Users[gender]" value="2" onclick="getcaleder();" >Female 
<input type="text" name="date_of_birth" id="Users_date_of_birth">
```

I want to load two different calenders in the date_of_birth text field based on choosing male or female.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

      $("#Users_gender_0").prop("checked", true);

      var dt = new Date();
      var day = dt.getDate();
      var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
      var girlyear = dt.getFullYear() - 18;
      var boyyear = dt.getFullYear() - 21;

      $("#Users_date_of_birth").datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
          yearRange: '-50y:c+nn',
          maxDate: boyyear + '-' + month + '-' + day
      });


  });

  function getcaleder() {
      var gender = $('input[name= "Users[gender]" ]:checked').val();

      var dt = new Date();
      var day = dt.getDate();
      var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
      var girlyear = dt.getFullYear() - 18;
      var boyyear = dt.getFullYear() - 21;

      if (gender == 0) {

          var y = boyyear;
      } else {
          var y = girlyear;
      }

      $("#Users_date_of_birth").datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
          yearRange: '-50y:c+nn',
          maxDate: y + '-' + month + '-' + day
      });
  }
```

I gave the function like above. In document ready I made male gender checked and one calender loaded, but when clicking on female then function given for changing calender but calender not changed. Date picker loaded for female but same as gender is loaded.

```
I want calender till 1994 for males and till 1997 for females.
```

Please anyone help.

Comment: There is no element with id `#Users_date_of_birth` the ID is `#date_of_birth`. Use `$('#date_of_birth').datepicker(..);`

Comment: Please share plunker or JSFiddle for the problem

Comment: ya sorry..I changed the id, but not worked yet

Comment: Try adding `$('#Users_date_of_birth').datepicker("show");` after you initialise the picker..

Comment: date picker is loaded for female, but it is same as gender one..because gender calender is  loaded first.

Comment: @RakhiVijayan : Destroy calender in getCalender() method.$( "#Users_date_of_birth" ).datepicker( "destroy" ) before $("#Users_date_of_birth").datepicker({});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this in your function

```
      $("#Users_date_of_birth").datepicker("destroy");

      $("#Users_date_of_birth").datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
          yearRange: '-50y:c+nn',
          maxDate: y + '-' + month + '-' + day
      });
```

also check this link
https://jsfiddle.net/km9attz6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/fnRcL/393/

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" name="Users[gender]" value="1" onclick="getcalender()" >Male
<input type="radio" name="Users[gender]" value="2" onclick="getcalender()" >Female 
<input type="text" name="date_of_birth" id="date_of_birth">
```

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Users_gender_0").prop("checked", true);

    var dt = new Date();
    var day = dt.getDate();
    var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
    var girlyear = dt.getFullYear() - 18;
    var boyyear = dt.getFullYear() - 21;

    $("#date_of_birth").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        yearRange: '-50y:c+nn',
        maxDate: boyyear + '-' + month + '-' + day
    });


});

getcalender = function() {
    $( "#date_of_birth" ).datepicker( "destroy" )
    var gender = $('input[name= "Users[gender]" ]:checked').val();

    var dt = new Date();
    var day = dt.getDate();
    var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
    var girlyear = dt.getFullYear() - 18;
    var boyyear = dt.getFullYear() - 21;

    if (gender == 1) {
        var y = boyyear;
    } else {
        var y = girlyear;
    }

    $("#date_of_birth").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        yearRange: '-50y:c+nn',
        maxDate: y + '-' + month + '-' + day
    });
};
```